# PHP Curl - Operation abort if the user disconnected

Tags: php, curl

I have this code here to allow the users to download files over my server:

```
$ch_2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0');
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_URL, $download_link);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 10240);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 60);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 500);
curl_exec($ch_2);
$curl_errno_2 = curl_errno($ch_2);
curl_close($ch_2);
```

Theese files (linked in $download_link) are very big, around 1-3 GB.

**This code works fine, but my problem is, when a user disconnects or abort the download then the script doesn't stop until the server has received the full file ($download_link).**

If I set "ignore_user_abort(true)", then the script stops, but is it possible to check a client disconnection or download abort in the script and can handle this? For example, update a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database entry or something else?

I know I can change this code by using "readfile()" or fopen, fread for example, but I will (and must) use this [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) code.

Is it possible to check this user disconnection or download abort, because I will only allow the user to make one download connection per [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)? So if they abort a download I can not update my MySQL database to mange the download connections form this IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a shutdown function. This will be called when the script finishes, when the user aborts or when you call exit() or die(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

For example, (from `php.net`):

```
<?php
    function shutdown()
    {
        // This is our shutdown function, in
        // here we can do any last operations
        // before the script is complete.

        echo 'Script executed with success', PHP_EOL;
    }

    register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
?>
```

That's the closest you're going to get.

> "because I will only allow the user to make one download connection per IP address?"

I would suggest you do this:

1. Use [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to store an IP address that is currently downloading something
2. Register a shutdown function to remove the IP address from APC allowing them to download something else

Comment: And that works if i had set "ignore_user_abort(false)" and the client connection disconnected?

Comment: Yes, then the shutdown function will execute, i also added the extra bit on the end about using APC (which i added after seeing your updated question)

Comment: however, php can't detect the remote abort until it tries to perform output.

Comment: I was about to use this solution, then I found out that I could accomplish the same thing using `__destruct()` function inside the class that used the cURL